# Scala comparing generics?

Tags: scala, generics, binary-search, comparator

I am writing a generic binary search implementation and I am failing to compile this (`compare is not a member of type parameter B`) even though `B` is an `Ordering` and it should be converted implicitly to `Ordered` which has the `compare` method:

```
  /**
   * Generic binary search in (min,max) f to achieve target goal
   * O(log n)
   *
   * @param f the function to binary search over - most be monotonically increasing
   * @param min starting minimum guess (must be exclusive)
   * @param max starting maximum guess (must be exclusive)
   * @param avg mid function usually (min+max)/2
   * @param goal target to achieve
   * @tparam A input type of f
   * @tparam B output type of f
   * @return Some(x) such that f(x) is goal else None
   */
  import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._

  def binarySearch[A: Ordering, B: Ordering](f: A => B, min: A, max: A, avg: (A, A) => A, goal: B): Option[A] = {
    if (min >= max) {
      None
    } else {
      val mid = avg(min, max)
      f(mid) compare goal match {
        case  1 => binarySearch(f, min, mid, avg, goal)
        case -1 => binarySearch(f, mid, max, avg, goal)
        case  0 => Some(mid)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try importing [`scala.math.Ordered`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordered%24):

```
import scala.math.Ordered._
```

It has an implicit conversion of elements of type `B` to `Ordered` granted that there is an `Ordering` typeclass for type `B` in scope.